# Unique Reports - Chainlink OCR2Base.sol

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I was checking the OCR2Base.sol file in the CCIP repo and was wondering what the `i_uniqueReports` variable stands for. Especially, why would it change the `transmit()` function such that the expected number of signatures changes:

```
uint256 expectedNumSignatures;
if (i_uniqueReports) {
  expectedNumSignatures = (configInfo.n + configInfo.f) / 2 + 1;
} else {
  expectedNumSignatures = configInfo.f + 1;
}
if (rs.length != expectedNumSignatures) revert WrongNumberOfSignatures();
if (rs.length != ss.length) revert SignaturesOutOfRegistration();
```

I have taken a look at their [older OCR PDF](https://research.chain.link/ocr.pdf), but I don't see anything that may resemble this.

You can see the shared excerpt in the following link at line 219:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/ccip/blob/ccip-develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ccip/ocr/OCR2Base.sol

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that Smart Contracts verify signatures on-chain, which can be costly. The more signatures, the higher the cost, so we should have as few signatures as possible. A report is considered valid if it has `f+1` signatures, which means that at least one of the `f+1` signers is correct. Remember that `f` is the maximum number of potentially malicious oracles. This may be enough for some use cases.

However, there is a scenario where the current leader of OCR report generation can be malicious and force a subset of oracles to create report `r`, while another subset creates report `r'`. Since `f+1` oracles sign both reports, they are considered valid but not unique. As a result, one transmitter might transmit report `r` while another might transmit report `r'`.

We use the uniqueReports flag to avoid this scenario, which forces each report to be signed by `2f+1` oracles. This ensures that it is impossible to have two different subsets of oracles that sign different reports. Since we only have `3f+1` oracles in total, the two sets would intersect at least once with a correct oracle that would not sign both `r` and `r'`. This property is known as the quorum intersection.

By setting the uniqueReports flag, a transmitter can only ever transmit a unique report. However, even with `f+1` signatures, we can depend on the blockchain to choose which report to finalize first among r and r'. This may be acceptable for some use cases but not for others.

OCR3 combines the best of both worlds, as it only requires `f+1` signatures to be verified on-chain but always produces unique reports. This is achieved by decoupling consensus on unique reports from gathering signatures on the reports.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity! May I ask then, what would be some use cases in which it would be considered less problematic not to have unique reports?
Also, where could I find info as detailed as your answer for OCR2 and OCR3? I can't find much beyond Youtube conference videos and these are a bit too superficial.

Comment: A note for a future reader: `2f + 1` arises as the minimum condition that satisfies `n >= 3f`, in the sense that `((configInfo.n + configInfo.f) / 2 + 1) >= 2f + 1`